# How do I get the req.url in vcl_backend_response?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

My configs are based on Varnish 3.0 and I have been updating them. But I ran into a snag.

`vcl_fetch` was replace to `vcl_backend_response`. Inside of `vcl_fetch` you used to be able to use `req.url` but not anymore inside of `vcl_backend_response`.

So I am left with three `if` statements that won't work:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
     set beresp.do_esi = true;

     if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
           unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
     }

     if ( req.http.host ~ "[0-9]\.example\.com" || req.http.host ~ "[0-9]\.example\.com") {
          set beresp.ttl = 60s;
     }

     if ( req.url ~ "\.(html|htm|css|js|txt|xml|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=]+)?$" ) {
          set beresp.do_gzip = true;
     }
}
```

How do I convert these configs in Varnish version 4.0?

By the way I am new to Varnish VCL.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to use `bereq.url` now in `vcl_backend_response`.